# Issue with SLF4J while calculating total duration of MP4 files in a directory

Tags: java, maven, jar, slf4j

#### Main Goal:

My main goal was to get the duration of all `.mp4` files from a directory. So, I have googled it and found [this qeustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984612/how-can-i-get-video-length-in-java) where one answer referred [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/xuggler/inspect-a-video-file-with-xuggler/) for full code.

#### Error in import:

When I took the necessary portion in my code, it was showing error in the following line:

```
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;
```

After that, I downloaded Xuggler from [here](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar) which I got from [here](http://www.xuggle.com/downloads). Then I got the following Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.<clinit>(JNILibrary.java:42)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:14)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.Ferry.<clinit>(Ferry.java:25)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.<clinit>(IContainer.java:1622)
    at videotimecalcualtioncoursera.MainFrame.calculateTime(MainFrame.java:116)
    at videotimecalcualtioncoursera.MainFrame.jButtonCalculateActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:284)
    at videotimecalcualtioncoursera.MainFrame.access$000(MainFrame.java:33)
    at videotimecalcualtioncoursera.MainFrame$4.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:204)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 45 more
```

#### Solving the Exception "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory":

To seek the solution of the above exception, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434862/xuggle-error-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf) and tried all its three solution with no luck. Got the following exception:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ee76520, pid=10112, tid=3292
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [xuggle6026878147022032067.dll+0x736520]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# H:\Dropbox\JavaProjects\VideoTimeCalcualtionCoursera\hs_err_pid10112.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Java Result: 1
```

#### Solving the Exception "SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder":

Seeking the solution of it, I got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder) and the accepted answer could do nothing except removing the first three lines in error stream.

#### What I have tried then:

I have tried adding the following `.jar` files in my project:

1. xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar
2. slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar / slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
3. slf4j-simple-1.7.6.jar / slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar
4. log4j-1.2.16.jar
5. logback-classic-1.0.0.jar
6. logback-core-1.0.6.jar
7. slf4j-jdk14-1.7.12.jar
8. slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar

#### File - hs_err_pid10112.log:

You can see the error file [here](http://pastebin.com/Q2N1BXAU), I could not added it as adding it would cross the character limit.

How to resolve this problem?

#### Note:

I have traversed along the following questions:

1. [using Logback with slf4j [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001739/using-logback-with-slf4j)
2. [Error with Slf4j and classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429758/error-with-slf4j-and-classpath)
3. [Given I'm stuck with SLF4J and java.util.Logging, what is optimal solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433085/given-im-stuck-with-slf4j-and-java-util-logging-what-is-optimal-solution)
4. [How do I get a list of configured loggers using Jboss LogManager with SLF4J?](http://How%20do%20I%20get%20a%20list%20of%20configured%20loggers%20using%20Jboss%20LogManager%20with%20SLF4J?)
5. [How to write event logs into xml files with SLF4J or Logback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626291/how-to-write-event-logs-into-xml-files-with-slf4j-or-logback)
6. [OpenJPA logging with slf4j on WebSphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703105/openjpa-logging-with-slf4j-on-websphere)
7. [Tomcat Logging With Slf4j and Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012595/tomcat-logging-with-slf4j-and-log4j)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the issue, but I could achieve my goal in other way.

I have used IBM's tool kit for it.

1. Downloaded IBM's API from [here](http://repository.mygrid.org.uk/artifactory/list/keep/com/ibm/IBMPlayerForMpeg4SDK/1.0.0/IBMPlayerForMpeg4SDK-1.0.0.jar).
2. Added the following code snippet in my code:

   ```
   public long getDuration(File file) throws IOException {
       PlayerControl playerControl = PlayerFactory.createLightweightMPEG4Player();
       playerControl.open(file.getAbsolutePath());
       return playerControl.getDuration();
   }
   ```

As my goal was only getting the duration, this is not the efficient way.

In my PC (core-i5, 2.5GHz, 6GB RAM, Win10), It took `42657ms` to process 60 `.mp4` files which outputted **Around 6 Hours 41 Minutes of Duration**.

If you want, you can check it in [my repository](https://github.com/enamcse/VideoTimeCalcualtionMP4/releases/tag/v0.1).

Answer (score 1):

You will usually need three functional parts:

1. the API used by the program (slf4j-api)
2. bridging code to adapt the logger implementation to the SLF4J API (e.g. slf4j-log4j12) this one must match the logger you use.
3. the logger implementation (e.g. log4j)

Some jars cover more than one part, e.g. logback covers 2 and 3 because it implements slf4j natively or if you use java util logging you don't need to explicitly add part 3 (it is in the Java runtime)

You must also use matching versions of the slf4j components, for example don't mix slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar with slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar.

Have a look at the [slf4j documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/) for the details.

Comment: I have all in version 1.7.12 now. but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding your dependencies one by one (while commenting out dependent code).  My first impression is that one of these libraries features incompatible versions/backends for slf4j on their classpaths.  it's impossible to know which one until you discover this.  Once you do that, you can get gradle/maven to exclude one of the conflicting things from your classpath.

Comment: I also have tried adding all the updated version, that means 1.7.12 @Jerry

Comment: @manetsus: you have like five logging backends in your list of dependencies.  Your code will break if you have more than one.

Comment: I did not added them simultaneously. say, I have tried with 1,2,3,7 or 1,2,3,8 and such like combinations as described in the answers of the related questions which I linked.